# Xcode with OS X Server hangs on "Choose the devices that this bot will test with:"

Tags: ios, xcode, osx-server

I am on a corporate network, so connectivity is often an issue.

I am trying to connect Xcode to my **local** OS X Server.

I am connecting to 127.0.0.1 and when I go to create a bot it hangs on "Choose the devices that this bot will test with" and has "Test With: Loading platforms..."

What is it doing at this stage so I can try to fix the issue?

Xcode 7.2
El Capitan 10.11.3

Thanks

Comment: OS X Server is running on your own system, and you are connecting to your own host via the loopback interface?  What does corporate network connectivity issues have to do with that?

Comment: Initially I had a number of issues finding proxy settings to connect to GIT etc.

So yes, at the moment, I connected by setting my Xcode to connect to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Trying to configure a bot on your client presumes Xcode Server has been launched and configured. So you've setup Xcode Server on your Mac, and configured it via the Server app?

Comment: @PetahChristian Yes, that is correct. I have OS X server connected and running. I have gone to services -> Xcode -> Chosen version. I have turned on the service. The one thing that I have not done is add the Xcode server to a development team. I assume that is only needed for archiving, and not for testing. Thanks